# Automated Bat File Not Working For Service Account

Tags: batch-file

We have a file that we send to the bank and it worked via bat file when sending through FTPS.exe but not we must use PSFTP.exe which works for the desktop user but not the service account.  We have tried logging in as the service account user and running the process which works when we are logged in as but not when scheduled through a Windows Server.  Have also tried putting the Y in the bat file to answer the validate question whcih we have to answer only once when using desktop user without success.

I have read a lot of hits online pointing to authentication, using two files, etc... but not sure how to implement them.  I would really appreciate assistance with this.

here is my bat file which is called by Gentran as an executeable, server is Windows 2008 R2, Service Pack1:

```
SET MOVEitIP=FTX-SERVSH.bnymellon.com
SET MOVEitUser=******
SET MOVEitPassword=******
echo cd /inbound/trp/ >> frommoveit.txt
echo mput D:\GENSRVNT\PositivePay\*.txt >> frommoveit.txt
echo quit >> frommoveit.txt
psftp -batch %MOVEitIP% -l %MOVEitUser% -pw %MOVEitPassword% -b frommoveit.txt
del frommoveit.txt
```

Basically took script from bat file for FTPS.exe and updated it for PSFTP.exe to use.  Again, this works as desktop user and service account user (when signed into the server) but not when automated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Krise

Comment: Does it work when scheduled by task manager, but only if the user under whose credentials it runs is logged-in?

Comment: it did not work even with my credentials as a scheduled task.

Comment: More details, the task says it completed successfully but the file was not sent to the bank.  I was even logged on at the time it was scheduled for. I will however set it to run at its normal time and check it tomorrow morning to see if it works with a live file instead of the test file...don't see how it should make a difference though.

Comment: The Task Scheduler did not work this morning, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The service account must have the "Log On Locally" rights otherwise the account will not be able to logon to execute the sheduled task. I think you will see the logon error in the eventvwr at the time the task was run.